# $A^\mathrm{T}A=B^\mathrm{T}B \Leftrightarrow \exists$ orthogonal $Q$ such that $A=QB$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, how can you prove the following:

$A^\mathrm{T}A=B^\mathrm{T}B \Leftrightarrow \exists$ orthogonal $Q$ such that $A=QB$

or is there a counterexample? Intuitively it makes sense to me, but I haven't found a nice proof yet. I have tried it through using SVD, but the non-uniqueness of the decomposition makes problems. I would be happy for some suggestions!

Comment: Possibly helpful: Your statement is wrong if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$. Thus, we need something specific to the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is formally real. That could be the fact that $\operatorname{Ker}\left(C^T C\right) = \operatorname{Ker} C$ for any matrix $C$ over the reals.

Comment: Yes, it does help. This fact shows that $\operatorname{Ker} A = \operatorname{Ker} B$. Now, working with linear maps instead of matrices, we can let $P$ be the canonical projection from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^{n} / \operatorname{Ker} A = \mathbb{R}^{n} / \operatorname{Ker} B$. Then, each of $A$ and $B$ factor through $P$, that is, we have $A = A'P$ and $B = B'P$ for some linear maps $A'$ and $B'$ from that quotient space. These linear maps $A'$ and $B'$ are injective. Now, $A^T A = B^T B$ becomes $P^T A'^T A' A = P^T B'^T B' P$.

Comment: This easily yields $A'^T A' = B'^T B'$ thanks to the surjectivity of $P$. The nice thing about the two maps $A'$ and $B'$ is that they are injective (as opposed to $A$ and $B$, which may and may not be). Hence, your question is reduced to the case of both $A$ and $B$ being injective (because if $A' = QB'$, then clearly $A = A'P = QB'P = QB$).

Comment: Now, assuming that $A$ and $B$ are injective, we can look at the map $B\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right) \to A\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ which sends every $Bv$ to $Av$ (this is well-defined, because $B$ is injective and so every element of $B\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ can be written as $Bv$ for exactly one $v$). This map is an isometry (because check that $\left(Bv, Bv'\right) = \left(Av, Av'\right)$ for any $v$ and $v'$). By Witt's theorem ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt%27s_theorem ), this isometry can be extended to an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^m$ to itself. This extended isometry is your $Q$ !

Comment: I hope someone with more time at hand can expend some of it to write this up as an answer, possibly avoiding the overkill(?) of using Witt's theorem. Nice question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preparation for my exam, I tackled the problem of solving this old (and not quite resolved) question and came up with a nice solution. I hope the people who stared the problem will like the answer :).

Let's prove a more general theorem: 
Let $A: V \rightarrow W$  and $B: V \rightarrow W$ be linear operators on finite-dimensional inner-product spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Then the following holds:

> $A^{*}A = B^{*}B \Leftrightarrow \exists U: W \rightarrow W$ s.t. $U^*U = I_{W}$ and $UA = B$

**Proof:**

$\Leftarrow$: is trivial.

$\Rightarrow$: Using the Polar-Decomposition theorem, we know that 
$A = U_A (A^*A)^\frac{1}{2}$ and $B = U_B(B^*B)^\frac{1}{2}$, where ${U_A}^{*}U_A = {U_B}^{*}U_B = I_W$. Now, since $B^*B = A^*A$, we have $U_B{U_A}^*A = U_B{U_A}^*U_A (A^*A)^\frac{1}{2} = U_B (A^*A)^\frac{1}{2} = U_B (B^*B)^\frac{1}{2} = B$. Thus, per construction we found our desired $U$ to be $U = U_B{U_A}^*$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Leftarrow$ is trivial.

for $\implies$:
consider $A = (A_1, \dots A_d)$ as a family of columns.
Then the hypothesis writes $A_i\cdot A_j = B_i\cdot B_j$.

Consider a subfamily that generates $\text{span }\{A_k\}$. 
You can find a set $I$ such as $\text{span }\{A_k\} = \text{span }\{A_i, i\in I\} $.

As for every matrix $C$, $\text{rank }C = \text{rank }C^TC$,
you get that $
\{B_i, i\in I\}
$ is a basis of $\text{span }\{B_k\}$.

Eventually,
consider the linear map
$$
f: \text{span }\{B_k\}\to \text{span }\{A_k\}
\\
i\in I \implies f(B_i) = A_i
$$

This is an orthogonal transformation and you can define it in any way to $R^d$, keeping the orthogonality. Its matrix $Q$ is such as $QB = A$.